# How to use enter key on a Login/Password window in c++?

Tags: c++, windows, keyboard, window

I am trying to add the possibility to use the RETURN key in an already made Login/Password form.

The thing is, I didn't make the form, and it is the first time I've used the Window API for Windows. So there is a lot I don't know...

So basically, a window is created, and inside of it, three child "windows" are created.

One editable: Login
A second one editable: Password
And a button: OK

Basically, I added a handle for the WM_CHAR in the message callback method:

```
else if (msg == WM_CHAR)
{
    if (wParam == VK_RETURN)
    {
        char    BufLogin[128];
        char    BufPasswd[128];

        GetWindowText(hwndEditLogin, BufLogin, sizeof(BufLogin));
        GetWindowText(hwndEditPasswd, BufPasswd, sizeof(BufPasswd));
        print_msg(BufLogin);
        print_msg(BufPasswd);
        return (0);
    }
    else
        return (DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam));
}
```

(I also tried by replacing WM_CHAR with WM_KEYDOWN to no success.)

I checked on stack overflow, and the only solutions I've found so far talk of things I don't understand, or simply don't work...
I added a check in the message loog like so:

```
while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    if (!IsDialogMessage(hWnd, &msg) || msg.wParam == VK_RETURN)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
```

And it did work, unless the user had clicked on any child window... Basically, it worked if the user hadn't clicked on anything or modified anything, which makes the Login/password part of the window pretty useless! ^^'

So what I'm guessing is that the (!IsDialogMessage) check rules out the WM_CHAR and the WM_KEYDOWN messages (still allowing the user to type for some reason), and if I add the check for the wParam, it works but only for the parent window.

If you guys had any idea on how to work aroun this conundrum of mine, I would be so grateful! Thanks in advance! :)

(P.S.: I edited this question, before I asked on how to make the TAB key work, because the IsDialogMessage check would make each character appear four times. I simply forgot to put the `!` before the IsDialogMessage! ^^'
I make this note in case anyone found my question and had the same problem I had before editing! ;) )

Comment: Emulating Dialog Box behavior with a regular window is certainly possible but it's difficult to do it completely right (imho). Why don't you just use Dialog Template in a RC file and the API CreateDialog?

Comment: Well... As I said, this part of the code isn't mine! :s
And I have no idea on how to usethe Dialog template! :/

Comment: Ok, with a bit more understanding of what I'm doing, here's a proper answer to your comment:
RC files are a no-no, because the windows have to be runtime editable!

And I made the code work by adding the  forgotten `!` before IsDialogMessage! ^^'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I've finally figured it out! Here's my solution for it if anyone needs to do the same! ;)

I made two global variables, one for each window that needs to handle the ENTER key:

```
WNDPROC wpOldEditProcPass;
WNDPROC wpOldEditProcLogin;
```

Then I created two `CALLBACK` methods, again, one for each window:
(Placed them before my main `CALLBACK`)

```
LRESULT CALLBACK    CustomEditProcLogin(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam,        LPARAM lParam)
{
switch (msg)
{
    case WM_CHAR:
    {
        if (wParam == VK_RETURN)
        {
            SendMessage(GetParent(hWnd), WM_COMMAND, MAKEWPARAM(ID_BUTTON, BN_CLICKED), 0);
            return(0);
        }
    }
}
CallWindowProc(wpOldEditProcLogin, hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK    CustomEditProcPass(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
switch (msg)
{
    case WM_CHAR:
    {
        if (wParam == VK_RETURN)
        {
            SendMessage(GetParent(hWnd), WM_COMMAND,     MAKEWPARAM(ID_BUTTON, BN_CLICKED), 0);
            return(0);
        }
    }
}
CallWindowProc(wpOldEditProcPass, hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

In the main `CALLBACK`, in the WM_CREATE handle, after I created the child windows, I subclassed them:

```
wpOldEditProcPass = (WNDPROC)SetWindowLongPtr(hwndEditPasswd, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)CustomEditProcPass);
wpOldEditProcLogin = (WNDPROC)SetWindowLongPtr(hwndEditLogin, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)CustomEditProcLogin);
```

And then in WM_DESTROY, I gave them back their original process:
(Before PostQuitMessage(0); )

```
SetWindowLongPtr(hwndEditPasswd, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)wpOldEditProcPass);
SetWindowLongPtr(hwndEditLogin, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)wpOldEditProcLogin);
```

And then I replaced the:

```
if (!IsDialogMessage(hWnd, &msg))
```

With:

```
if (!IsDialogMessage(hWnd, &msg) ||(msg.message == WM_KEYDOWN && msg.wParam == VK_RETURN))
```

And it works like a charm! :D

(I still can't figure out why I have to allow a WM_KEYDOWN message, but handle a WM_CHAR message... If I allow a WM_CHAR message, it doesn't work, and if I handle a WM_KEYDOWN message, I get the obnoxious "Ding" sound when I press enter! ^^' )